# Oh My Zsh works in iTerm2 but other terminal emulators have display issue

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2, oh-my-zsh

I am on macOS, using the zsh shell with [oh-my-zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/).
Usually I use iTerm2, and it's a pretty nice experience. However, when I use another terminal emulator (such as `:term` in vim, or Terminal.app)
I see an odd issue where the command gets printed in the output.  I can't figure out why this is or how to fix it.

Here is a screenshot of iTerm2, where everything looks nice:
[image: iTerm2: no issue]

And here is the issue, using `:term` in vim: note how `ls` and `echo` are printed at the beginning of the output in each case, and `~` is repeated as well.
[image: nvim terminal (running in iTerm2)]

I get this issue in every terminal emulator I've tried other than iTerm2: I've tried

- kitty,
- Terminal.app,
- `:term` in vim and in nvim (running in Terminal.app or iTerm2),
- integrated terminal in VSCode,

with one exception: [vterm](https://melpa.org/#/vterm) in (doom) emacs looks great, just like iTerm2.

I'm pretty sure it's caused by Oh My Zsh somehow, since **the issue goes away when comment out the following line** in my `.zshrc`

```sh
source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

(but of course this isn't a fix, since I want to use omz!)

It doesn't seem to be related to any particular omz plugins I'm using, since the problem remains even when I comment out the `plugins = (...)` lines in my `.zshrc`.

Does anyone know what might be going on?  I don't really understand what's going in `oh-my-zsh.sh` file, but I imagine it's related to something in there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the culprit. If I remove the file
`$ZSH/lib/termsupport.zsh` (or rename it to have a different extension, so it isn't sourced by `oh-my-zsh.sh`), then the issue goes away.  This seems to be due to the functions

[`omz_termsupport_precmd`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/2d40b562e5da4c885babc1f7f09aa33a8a891eb2/lib/termsupport.zsh#L51) and [`omz_termsupport_preexec`](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/2d40b562e5da4c885babc1f7f09aa33a8a891eb2/lib/termsupport.zsh#L57)

**So the fix seems to be:** uncomment the line
`DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` in `.zshrc`